# Setting a formatted "ControlSource" of a textbox dynamically on report Rowsource change

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a Report as "Subform" in a Form where I have some control buttons.

If I press a Button to view some "archived file data", I am changing the rowsource of the report from the Query `qryDefaultview` to the Query `qryTempView` via vba. `qryTempView` is a dynamically generated query that can include include values of search fields on the form.

This works as intended, but to save up some screenspace, I have edited some textboxes that show dates on my report to show only the month and the last two digits of the year of the date. In the `ControlSource` window, it writes like this:

```
=Format$([qryDefaultview.Orderdate];"mm/jj")
```

How can I transfer this into a VBA prompt? I know how to format data via `Format()` prompt in VBA but I don't know how I can set the rowsource to a certain field of a query.

It's probably very easy, but I have spent quite some time on this Problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the Format property of that textbox to: *mm/yy*

and and leave its ControlSource as *OrderDate*

Comment: Thanks a lot. Sometimes the solution is too simple to see.